# googletest: death tests: multiple expect_exit in single test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Is it possible to use more than one EXPECT_EXIT macros in a single test on the Windows platform? 
The problem occurs because on the Windows platform death tests work in a "threadsafe" mode, so the process spawned by EXPECT_EXIT macros will run all the test from the beginning. Consider sample code:

```
TEST_F(MyFixtureDeathTest, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EXIT(f(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(1), "message1");

//....
// actions after the exit (for instanse, emulation of the application correct restart)
//....

    EXPECT_EXIT(g(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(1), "message2");
}
```

So when the test gets to the second EXPECT_EXIT macros it will make the code to run from the test beginning, so it will invoke the f() function, make exit there and actually never get to the body of g() function.
Maybe, I shouldn't use the GoogleTest for this task at all, should I?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

UPD. (clarification) Actually, I'm quite sure now that in the described code snippet even the function f() won't be invoked from the process spawned by the the second EXPECT_EXIT macro.

UPD. The problem now seems a bit different to me. As VladLosev said, the first macro will be totally ignored in the child process spawned by the second macro. But in case of any asserts in the between of two macro based on the some results of f() function the child process will hit assert and exit there, so it won't be able to get to g().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this code will work as expected. A death test child process knows which death test macro it was invoked from and will only execute tested statement specified in that macro. E.g., in your code, the child proces invoked in the second `EXPECT_EXIT` macro will only execute `g()` and skip `f()`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot. So my problem is actually a bit different. The first macro body is totally skipped, so if it does some real work (creates a file, for instance), all the asserts that checks results in the middle between two macro will fail in the child process spawned by the second macro. That's the reason my code never come to the second macro body. Are there any possibilities to fix that?

Comment: The death test statements are not skipped, they are performed in a child process. This means that in-memory effects of such statement will not be seen in the main test body or other test statements. If such a statement creates a file it will be visible - just make sure it's flushed to disk. But if you save its name in a variable, that name will not be seen outside.

Comment: Also, as preceding test code is executed in every death test child process, avoid uisng functions generating unique file names in code with death tests - base temporary file names on name of the test instead. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Getting_the_Current_Test's_Name on how to access the test name.

Comment: But in your answer above you wrote that "in the second EXPECT_EXIT macro will only execute g() and skip f()". So, will f() be skipped or not in that particular case? Or, in other words, will child process spawn their own children processes in case of other death test statements inside?

Comment: The first EXPECT_DEATH macro will spawn one child process to execute f(). The second one will spawn another child process to execute g(). It will also run all the code from the start of the test to the start of the second - excluding f(). Two things follow: a) f() will be executed only once in the test and b) the second child process will not see any in-memory effects of calling f(). But it will of course see persistent effects (files created, etc.). And no, there are no second level child processes.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's absolutely clear. I forgot to mention that usually in the beginning of the test case the test file directory is cleared. That the reason of the specific behavior. Because child process from the second EXPECT_DEATH macro calls the function to clear the directory but skips f() which should fill it with data. Thanks one more time.